# Load data from csv with ETL in a specified cluster

Tags: orientdb

I have 4 csv data files which I would to load into 4 different clusters of a single class in OrientDB: a class named demo with 4 clusters named respectively demo14q4, demo15q1, demo15q2 and demo15q3. I have tried to create 4 ETL modules in which I define a loader with an option as follow (in this case for demo14q4 cluster):

```
"cluster": "demo14q4",
```

Other options of loader (classes, indexes, etc.) are defined as usual.

My problem is that if I haven't previously created classes, all data from single csv will loaded in single class named demo with only one cluster; but if I previously create the clusters, all data from single csv will be distribuited in all 4 clusters created.

I would to create a JSON ETL module where I can define in which cluster I can load my csv and only in that, if possible.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.